# Bulk Move Wordpress Post via php script

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to move all post from slug/Category (latestnews ) to (latestnews_archives) daily at 12 AM, ANYThing posted on latest news cat should be moved to latestnews_archives
WE DAILY UPDATE UPTO 20 POSTS IN LATEST NEWS, I DONT WANT TIMEOUT OCCUR WHILE MOVING POSTS TO LATEST NEWS ARCHIVES
ps: author should not change just posts will be moved

i want to create a php script automove.php will consists of wp db crenditials and sql query and i will put that script for cornjob daily at 12AM

NO PLUGINS PLEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put below code in  same WordPress directory where wp-config.php file is located

```
<?php  include_once("wp-config.php");
include_once("wp-includes/wp-db.php");
$sql = "update wp_term_relationships set term_taxonomy_id= (select term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_taxonomy where term_id=973) where term_taxonomy_id= (select term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_taxonomy where term_id=192)";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql); ?>
```

Replace 973 with your category ID Where you want to move
and replace 192 with category where posts are located
save file as anything.php
execute via cornjob